# How to hide an Excel workbook from VBA but NOT a UserForm?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to make a GUI-like interface for an Excel workbook, and I don't want the workbook to be visible until it closes. However, making the workbook not visible messes with the references of my code and I cannot read the ranges without heavily modifying it. I tried minimizing the window, but that minimizes the form as well.

Is there a way to keep the active workbook active but not readily visible, and the form visible?

Comment: If this happens: "*However, making the workbook not visible messes with the references of my code and I cannot read the ranges without heavily modifying it.*" Then you are probably using `.Select` or `.Activate` in your code. This is a bad practice and is highly recommended to be avoided (many undefined issues and slow code). If this is the case google for how to avoid using them both, there are many tutorials. Yes, removing them can be a lot of work, but saves you much time in future debugging and makes your code a lot better.

Comment: I would have thought there's no need to keep the workbook active - can't you just reference the workbook/sheet using a variable? This works fine for me and I can still reference any sheet on any workbook I like:  `Private Sub Workbook_Open(): Application.Visible = False: UserForm1.Show: End Sub`

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Yes, that's what I said. Don't use `.Select` and `.Activate` instead reference the worksheet directly like `Worksheets("MySheetName").Range("A1")`. But I think because he said hiding the sheet messes up his references he is using `.Select` and he has to change that to not using `.Select` and reference directly. Then the references would still work even after hiding the workbook.

Comment: Yeah sorry, think I wrote my comment at the same time as you.  After checking my little bit of code did what I said it did you'd already posted, but didn't want to waste the 5 minutes it took to test my code so posted anyway. :)

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Ahh, no need to be sorry, I thought you meant me with your comment not him haha. That was confusing me. Now that makes more sense that this comment was meant for *Viriax*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include the following when you load the userform

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ThisWorkbook.Application.Visible = False
End Sub
```

and this for when you end the userform (return to normal state)

```
Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()
    ThisWorkbook.Application.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me. However, I had to change it to Application.Visible = True, if I left "ThisWorkbook." it would not reappear.

Answer (score -1):

put this code in form's **UserForm_Initialize** method

```
ActiveWindow.Visible = False
```